# Horizontal scroll on mobile safari

Tags: html, ios, css, responsive-design, mobile-safari

I want to create a page with a black box in the middle, which has 30px of padding on the left and right hand side.

The following code works on desktop browsers without having a horizontal scroll, but on mobile safari you can scroll left and right. How do I prevent this horizontal scroll?

I have tried adding overflow: hidden to the body, the outer div and the inner div, this doesn't seem to help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>hello world</title>
</head>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0;">

<div style="padding:0 30px">
    <div style="background-color:#000;height: 50px;">

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try taking out the "width=device-width".  I just ran into this yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the answer was to wrap the div with the padding on it with another div.

```
<body style="margin:0;padding:0;">
<div>
    <div style="padding:0 30px">
        <div style="background-color:#000;height: 50px;">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```